# What kind of data do Google and Samsung collect from the OS itself?

Tags: samsung, google, privacy

Not including apps and websites. I've switched to open source phone, SMS, calendar, etc. and I use the DuckDuckGo browser to try to block some of the web trackers. What kind of data can Google and Samsung still see through stuff like Google Play Services and other OS level stuff? I assume they're still scanning WiFi and Bluetooth signals to try and approximate your location. What data do they collect and can it be stopped without flashing a custom ROM?

Comment: No one can tell. Read their privacy policy if your believe in what they say.